# How to access nested data using python

Tags: python

I have a function that gives me the following output:`<br>`
Output of `print(get_data[0])`:

```
{ 
'data': ({'top_data': {'center': (-71, 90), 'coord': 1},
                      {'id': 0, 'pos': (48, 205)},
                      {'top_data': {'center': (   7, 10, 40), 'coord': 1.5},
                      {'id': 1, 'pos': (43, 105)}),
         'centers_ob':{0: (19, 14, -20), 1: (-49, 22, 26)}, 'time': 13}
```

I would like to access `top_data` parameters, as well as `centers_ob` and `time` parameters. `<br>`
How could I get those values ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This looks really messy and very hard to follow can you please reformat.

Comment: `get_data[0]['data'][i]['top_data']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
data = {'data': ({'top_data': {'center': (-7, 1, 90), 'coord': 1}, 'id': 0, 'pos': (48, 205)}, {'top_data': {'center': (7, 10, 40), 'coord': 1.5}, 'id': 1, 'pos': (43, 105)}), 'centers_ob': {0: (19, 14, -20), 1: (-49, 22, 26)}, 'time': 13}
print(data['data'][0]['top_data'])
print(data['data'][1]['top_data'])
print(data['centers_ob'])
print(data['time'])
```

Though you should check [nested dict](https://nested-dict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)